# in elaboration of

Tags: phrase-usage, prepositional-phrases

The dictionary does not list "in elaboration of," but I'd like to know whether it is natural in the following:

> Peter delivered a series of lectures **in elaboration of** the theory.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?  Whether "elaboration of" is idiomatic, or whether there is a better way to say this?

Comment: Is it natural, i.e. idiomatic?

Comment: I would prefer "Peter delivered a series of lectures *to elaborate on* the theory." Presuming that the purpose of the lectures was to detail the theory, anyway. Your example isn't clear as to the relationship between the lectures and the theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**elaborating** is encountered [far more often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20elaboration%20of%2Celaborating&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20elaboration%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celaborating%3B%2Cc0) than **in elaboration of** but the latter collocation is grammatical.

The participle is a viable alternative to the prepositional phrase. For example:

> defying ... in defiance of
>   emulating ... in emulation of
>   honoring ...  in honor of
>   pursuing ... in pursuit of

The prepositional phrase is in a more formal register. Some might consider it a bit ponderous, others as imparting a certain *gravitas*.   A stylistic call. You'd have to consider the ambient tone.

Comment: "elaborating the theory"?

Comment: @user3169:  Not sure why you question that phrase. Care to elaborate?

Comment: When I put it into the example, I get "Peter delivered a series of lectures *elaborating the theory*." if that is what you meant. To me it seems like the "on" needs to be in there.

Comment: @user3169.  No, it does not need to be *elaborating **on|upon** the theory*.  The verb **to elaborate** can be  transitive, taking a direct object.  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22elaborating%20the%20theory%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en